# Summing 3D array elements with 1D arrays

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for a computer vision project, however, I need to do a pixel by pixel operation on the image which means accessing every pixel in a 640x480 image and changing it's HSV values. The image is made up of a 3D array X, Y and HSV Values, so a pixel at 130, 230 may have a HSV value of [12, 26, 18]  or represented in the image: (130, 230, (12, 26, 18))

I need to perform an operation which allows me to add an amount X into the V value (element index 2) of the HSV values: (130, 230, (12, 26, **18**))

I can do this using two loops:

```
for x in range(image.width):
        for y in range(image.height/2):
            initcolor = cv.Get2D(image, y, x)
            initcolor2 = [0, 0, 10, 0]
            summed = [sum(pair) for pair in zip(initcolor, initcolor2)] 
            cv.Set2D(image, y, x, summed)
```

But this is awfully slow and for some reason takes around 20 seconds to complete the operation over the entire image.

Is there a simpler, more faster way of achieving this?

Comment: Is it Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Can you convert your `cv` object into a 3D numpy-array of dimensions y*x*3, where in the third dimensions the HSV values would be stored and then manipulate on this? Search for 'numpy' here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface

Comment: If you replace `summed = [sum(pair) for pair in zip(initcolor, initcolor2)]` with `initcolor[2] = initcolor[2] + 10` and then `cv.Set2D(image, y, x, initcolor)`, how much of a speed increase do yo get?

Answer (score 1):

The first and easiest thing you should do is to check to see if OpenCV can take [numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays as arguments. Numpy is built on fast C algorithms that can handle large loops over data structures in what are called "vectorized" operations. Each loop in Python incurs a very large overhead.

Another alternative might be to put this block of code in [Cython](https://cython.org/), which can handle tight loops like this far better.

Comment: I created an image in openCV using cv.CreateImage and then set each pixel value in that image to [0, 0, X, 0]. Then I added the two images together using cv.Add. This has helped the speed somewhat, but I think the speed problem is coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing computer vision in Python, I would definitely use Numpy and get my arrays into numpy format as soon as possible.  I suspect you might want numpy.asarray() to convert from PIL to array.